# How to Store List of Java Objects/Json into Postgres Jsonb using JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

How do we define List of objects into postgres 9.6 jsonb data type using JPA? I'm trying to put list of products into order table's products column which should be of jsonb type;

use case:

```
 public class Order implements Serializable{
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long orderId;

   @Column(name = "products", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "jsonb")
        private List<Product> products;

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
     }
    public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
     }
    }


public class Product{
  private String productId;
  private String productName;
}
```